# form action changes to mail.php when visiting domain

Tags: php, forms, email, dns

I'm using a basic php for to mail myself from a website.
It's a single page website with the required PHP inside it, rather than a separate mail.php. I've used the built in validation and required fields, however when I visit the domain rather than domain/index.php the form code changes to make the action mail.php, no validation takes place and a blank email is sent.

I want it to have all fields required, validated then display a small success message to let the user know their message has been sent.
I've attached my code below.

```
<?php            
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
   $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
   $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
   $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
   $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
   $recipient = "me@domian";
   $subject = "Contact Form Subbmission";
   $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
   mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
   echo ("Thanks for getting in touch, I'll get back to you as soon as possible.");
}
//clean it
function test_input($data){
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>#contact">
<div class="row 50%">
<div class="6u"><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="required"/></div>
<div class="6u"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required"/></div>
</div>
<div class="row 50%">
<div class="12u"><textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="6" required="required">    </textarea></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="12u">
<ul class="actions">
<li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made a separate mail.php file on the server, this project is already over schedule.

Thanks for your answers

K

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
//checks if the post variables are set and also checks that they aren't empty         
if(isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['message'])&& $_POST['name'] !="" && $_POST['email'] !="" && $_POST['message'] !=""){
   $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
   $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
   $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
   $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
   $recipient = "me@domian";
   $subject = "Contact Form Subbmission";
   $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
   mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);
   echo 'Thanks for getting in touch, I\'ll get back to you as soon as possible.';
   }else{
   echo 'You didn\'t fill out all the fields. Please try again';
 }
//clean it
function test_input($data){
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
 }
?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
<div class="row 50%">
<div class="6u"><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="required"/></div>
<div class="6u"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required"/></div>
</div>
<div class="row 50%">
<div class="12u"><textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="6" required="required"></textarea></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="12u">
<ul class="actions">
<li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I set the form action to `index.php` just as example. You should set that to the file name of which all this code resides.

Answer (score 0):

In every case use better error handling then "or die" with the mail function.

eg;

```
<?php
 if(mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)){
     echo ("Thanks for getting in touch, I'll get back to you as soon as possible.");
 }
?>
```

Your form doesn't need this action. If it is posted to the domain itself, use the following:

```
<form method="post" action="#contact">
```

Comment: the action still changes itself to mail.php in the browser and ignores all validation

Comment: Is there a mail.php file on the server? Is this ALL the code you have on the server?

Comment: in this file, it's the only php. no mail.php file present.

Comment: If there is NOT a mail.php file at the server and this is your code, its practically impossible to send a email. Can you create a phpfiddle? http://codepad.viper-7.com/